# Debugger extension send thread event cannot update thread UI

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am developing a vscode debugger extension.  After the backend sends the thread event, the vscode thread UI will not be updated. Other functions are normal, such as breakpoints、step in、step out.
The environment is ubuntu 18.04, vscode 1.35.1

The thread event sent is

```
   {"type":"event","seq":61,"body": 
   {"reason":"exited","threadId":"122"},"event":"thread"}
```

Sending the same package is working on vimspector.
Why isn't the vscode updated? Is there anything I didn't think about?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your question and add the code in question?

Comment: Also, what language are you using? It's currently unclear.